# How can i return a dataReader using Entity Framework 6.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Exactly as the question asks.  I am using entity framework for most of my code, but i also need to execute and return a count or columns from a sql table that is not within my entity framework context.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `SqlConnection` with your connection string?

Comment: You can still use ADO.NET

Comment: I have used SqlConnection with ado.net at the moment, but i didnt know if creating a new SqlConnection was the right thing to do? or whether there was a way i could use EF connection, as if there is a transaction running, i want to use it

Comment: Why return columns that aren't in your EF context - why not add those tables to the context?

Comment: They are dynamic tables that i have no idea look like

Answer (score 6):

You can run a [raw query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) using Entity Framework, for example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

If you want to return a more complex type, you can define your own class and use that instead. As long as the properties match the names of the columns you select, it will work. So lets make a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And use it:

```
List<MyClass> result = ctx
    .Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("SELECT Id, UserName FROM dbo.Users")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But how would you return multiple columns? All different data types?

Comment: You can make your own non-entity class and use it. Check my edit.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot make a class because the table is dynamic and i do not know this at design time.  I do have the metadata of the column names at runtime

Comment: Thanks David. It suited perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an IDataReader is to Cursor through the data as it is being returned over the wire (exempli gratia TCP/IP) and thus not incur the overhead of stuffing it all into memory. If you're dealing with millions of rows, then reading everything into memory is a bad idea. If that is the case, then grab the underlying connection string from EF API and utilize ADO.NET. There's better better Aysnc support there as well.